# How can I connect my company with Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum

Hello Im very excited about the cryptocurrency revolution and believe strongly in its benefits. But could anyone give me some examples of how to connect your company with cryptocurrency? Greetings Robin

Comment: What do you mean by connecting your company to blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

If your company is looking to accept BTC or ETH as a payment you can use CoinBase, or Gemini's API's to accept payments.

Depending on the platform you use a plug-in may exist. It would be easier to answer with a more detailed question.

There is a lot of different ways and businesses that utilize blockchain technology.